# How do i fix these errors

Tags: error, fatal-error

I'm receiving these errors in the magento connect/update panel

```
 Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 2006 MySQL server has gone away' in /home/cleverop/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php:228 Stack trace:
#0 /home/cleverop/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php(228): PDOStatement->execute(Array)
#1 /home/cleverop/public_html/lib/Varien/Db/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php(110): Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array)
#2 /home/cleverop/public_html/app/code/core/Zend/Db/Statement.php(291): Varien_Db_Statement_Pdo_Mysql->_execute(Array)
#3 /home/cleverop/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(480): Zend_Db_Statement->execute(Array)
#4 /home/cleverop/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('SELECT `mg_core...', Array)
#5 /home/cleverop/public_html/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(428): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('SELECT `mg_core...', Array)
#6 /home/cleverop/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(828): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->query(Object(Varien_Db_Select), Arr in /home/cleverop/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php on line 235
```

I have no idea where they came from.

Comment: How do you mean not connected :P?

Comment: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/42176/geting-fatal-error-sqlstatehy000-general-error-2006-mysql-server-has-gone-a

Comment: Thank you! I will contact my hosting provider for this. If you make it an answer i can mark it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error occur because of mysql **execution time out**.

Refer following [URL](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/42176/geting-fatal-error-sqlstatehy000-general-error-2006-mysql-server-has-gone-a)