# Getting error "THERE HAS BEEN AN ERROR PROCESSING YOUR REQUEST" in Magento 1.8.1.0

Tags: magento-1.8, error, frontend

> In Magento ver. 1.8.1.0 I am getting error "THERE HAS BEEN AN ERROR
>   PROCESSING YOUR REQUEST"

[image]

Please can any one help on this.

**I tried to ask godaddy to update my.cnf file as guided in**

[Geting Fatal error: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 2006 MySQL server has gone away](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/42176/geting-fatal-error-sqlstatehy000-general-error-2006-mysql-server-has-gone-a)

but they are not able to help.

**I am getting this error on home page and category pages, Its strange some category page and cms pages are working fine.**

Thanks